# Manual model validation in Web API

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api

Web API comes with model validation support baked in: `ApiController.ModelState` provides a quick and painless way to see what's wrong with your input. Is there a way to get a similar `ModelStateDictionary` for any random object? I know about the `Validator` class, but looking at Web API's internals it seems to hook into quite a bit more than that.

Answer (score 0):

I have used [FluentValidation](https://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/) for generic purpose validation. It integrates with ASP.NET MVC, WebAPI, WinForms, etc.

I might have gotten used to it, but I remember its API seemed pretty straightforward when I first used it.

I'm thinking you can use this to get the validation results and convert them to a `ModelStateDictionary` if you really need to work with that.

For example, this is how you implement the validation rules:

```
public class CustomerValidator: AbstractValidator<Customer> {
  public CustomerValidator() {
    RuleFor(customer => customer.Surname).NotEmpty();
    RuleFor(customer => customer.Forename).NotEmpty().WithMessage("Please specify a first name");
    RuleFor(customer => customer.Discount).NotEqual(0).When(customer => customer.HasDiscount);
    RuleFor(customer => customer.Address).Length(20, 250);
    RuleFor(customer => customer.Postcode).Must(BeAValidPostcode)
                                          .WithMessage("Please specify a valid postcode");
  }

  private bool BeAValidPostcode(string postcode) {
    // custom postcode validating logic goes here
  }
}
```

And this is how you perform the actual validation:

```
Customer customer = new Customer();
CustomerValidator validator = new CustomerValidator();
ValidationResult results = validator.Validate(customer);

bool validationSucceeded = results.IsValid;
IList<ValidationFailure> failures = results.Errors;
```